# how to make character an image pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I got this code from a tutorial, but I added some stuff to make it into my own thing. A while back I was messing around and managed to make the controllable object an image. So I could move an image around the screen with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, but I changed it and forgot how to fix it now, and can't manage to `blit` it onto the screen. It's just a rectangle which I can move around the screen. How do I make it an image again?

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Altoria")
mc_front = pygame.image.load('bernie front.jpg')
mc_front = pygame.transform.scale(mc_front, (100, 160))
block = pygame.image.load('block.png')
block = pygame.transform.scale(block,(100,60))

block_x = 100
block_y = 50
x = 50
y = 400
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 20

run = True

while run:
    win.blit(block, [block_x, block_y])
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > vel:  # Making sure the top left position of our character is greater than our vel so we never move off the screen.
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 500 - vel - width:  # Making sure the top right corner of our character is less than the screen width - its width 
        x += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and y > vel:  # Same principles apply for the y coordinate
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and y < 500 - height - vel:
        y += vel

    win.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (250,0,0), (x, y, width, height))   
    pygame.display.update() 

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

A [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) (`A`) can drawn on another Surface (`B`) by [`B.blit(A, (x, y))`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). e.g:

```py
win.fill((0,0,0))

#pygame.draw.rect(win, (250,0,0), (x, y, width, height))   
win.blit(mc_front, (x, y))

pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end of your mainloop, you have it draw a rectangle, not an image. To blit the image onto the screen, the end of your mainloop would have to look like this:

```
win.fill((0,0,0)) #clear screen

win.blit(mc_front, (x, y)) #add player image

pygame.display.flip() #update the display
```

Comment: Oops. I just realized they are the same. You have enough reputation to delete my answer, should you wish.

Comment: No one can delete your answer.